# Intermittent GSAP Animation Issues with React Components in an Astro.js Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, astrojs

I'm working on a project using Astro.js that includes several React components. I've encountered a recurring issue where a block containing a GSAP animation doesn't behave as expected: the start marker of the animation seems to be misplaced, causing the animation to act as if it's the first element to load. Interestingly, this bug occurs sporadically and isn't reproducible on every page load, which makes it challenging to diagnose.

Here's what I've observed:

The issue is intermittent and doesn't happen on every page load.
When the bug occurs, the GSAP animation start marker appears to be offset, leading to incorrect animation behavior.
The rest of the React components on the page seem to be unaffected.
I'm looking for insights into what might be causing this erratic behavior and how to resolve it. Are there known compatibility issues between GSAP and Astro.js, or could this be related to the loading/lifecycle timing of React components within an Astro.js environment?

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue or improve the reliability of the GSAP animations within this setup would be greatly appreciated.

Here's screenshot of incorrect behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6enB7.png)

Here's screenshot of correct behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4MU4.png)

Comparing screenshots we can see that in case of incorrect behavior we get the situation that the start marker is near the beginning of the page, however, it should be closer to its middle, i.e. it is after some elements

```
const Cases = () => {
  const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768 ? true : false
  const yPercentValues = {
    mta: isMobile ? -104 : -100,
    kemFirstTimeMove: isMobile ? -100 : -100,
    kemSecondTimeMove: isMobile ? -208 : -200,
    biogeekFirstTimeMove: isMobile ? -207 : -200,
    biogeekSecondTimeMove: isMobile ? -312 : -300,
    shokecrsFirstTimeMove: isMobile ? -312 : -300,
    shokecrsSecondTimeMove: isMobile ? -416 : -400
  }
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      const anim = gsap
        .timeline()
        .to('.broex', {
          rotateX: -10,
          scaleX: 0.95,
          scaleY: 0.75
        })
        .to(
          '.broex img',
          {
            opacity: 0.7
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.mta',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.mta
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.kem',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.kemFirstTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.biogeek',
          {
            yPercent: -100
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.shockers',
          {
            yPercent: -100
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to('.mta', {
          rotateX: -10,
          scaleX: 0.95,
          scaleY: 0.75
        })
        .to(
          '.mta img',
          {
            opacity: 0.7
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.biogeek',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.biogeekFirstTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.shockers',
          {
            yPercent: -200
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.kem',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.kemSecondTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to('.kem', {
          rotateX: -10,
          scaleX: 0.95,
          scaleY: 0.75
        })
        .to(
          '.kem img',
          {
            opacity: 0.7
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.biogeek',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.biogeekSecondTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to(
          '.shockers',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.shokecrsFirstTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to('.biogeek', {
          rotateX: -10,
          scaleX: 0.95,
          scaleY: 0.75
        })
        .to(
          '.shockers',
          {
            yPercent: yPercentValues.shokecrsSecondTimeMove
          },
          '<'
        )
        .to('.shockers', {
          rotateX: -10,
          scaleX: 0.95,
          scaleY: 0.75
        })
        .to(
          '.shockers img',
          {
            opacity: 0.7
          },
          '<'
        )

      ScrollTrigger.create({
        animation: anim,
        trigger: '.case-wrapper',
        start: 'top 5%',
        end: '+=3000px',
        scrub: 1,
        toggleActions: 'play none none reverse',
        pin: true,
        markers: true,
      })
    })

    return () => {
      ctx.revert();
      ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((st) => st.kill());
      ScrollTrigger.refresh();
    }
  }, [])
```

Here you can see the animation code itself

```
  <Layout>
    <Hero client:only='react' className='content' />
    <About client:only='react' />
    <Cases client:only='react' />
    <Reviews client:only='react' />
    <QuestionsBlock client:only='react' />
  </Layout>
```

Here you can see a way to use the animation code

In an attempt to resolve the intermittent issue with the GSAP animation start marker, I implemented a workaround using GSAP's ScrollTrigger plugin. I added the following lines of code to kill all existing ScrollTriggers and then refresh them:

```
ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((st) => st.kill());
ScrollTrigger.refresh();
```

I added this code right before initializing my animations with the hope that it would reset any potentially misaligned start markers due to dynamically loaded content or changes in layout that occur after the initial page load. My expectation was that by killing and refreshing the ScrollTriggers, I would ensure that the animations would always start from the correct position, regardless of any previous state or interactions.

After implementing this change, I noticed that the erroneous behavior of the GSAP animations became less frequent. However, the issue still arises occasionally, which suggests that while this approach mitigates the problem to some extent, it does not fully resolve it. I was expecting a more consistent and reliable behavior of the animations with this workaround.

I'm looking to understand why this solution only partially works and what alternative approaches could lead to a more definitive fix for the erratic animation behavior in my Astro.js and React project.